# Pentaho Data Integration Does not support IAM for authorization in S3 Output File Step

Tags: authentication, amazon-s3, authorization, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I am trying to upload a file to S3 which requires AWS credentials and a specific IAM role as well. I can connect using AWS CLI tools and Java SDK, but PDI 8.2 does not seem to support AWS roles or profiles for authentication and authorization.

Therefore, any S3 Step fails with a 403:

Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied

I can use a shell script to send put objects to S3 via AWS CLI, but would prefer to use the S3 Step in PDI.

**Is there a way for a PDI transformation S3 step to use AWS key, secret, profile and/or role for authorization?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and Install AWS Cli interface
2. Then issue aws configure command into DOS command interface
3. Then assign Secret Key, Access Key, Regio as instructed by the AWS Cli
4. Its done

If you still face any issue, check IAM Role Policy once again. That should be as follows:

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "SaveObject4mExternal",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"AWS": "arn:aws:iam:::root"
},
"Action": [
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:PutObject",
"s3:DeleteObject"
],
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::/*"
}
]
}